# Live web server does not display table data with console log returning an http 500 error, while local hosting the project displays the data correctly

Tags: php, http, nginx

When using a local hosted XAMPP server, I am able to pull the data from my database and display them in html tables how I want them to display, but when I uploaded the files to the actual web server, I am getting an http 500 error. My local and webserver database are set up the same way with the same column names and everything. It doesn't seem like a connection error, as there is no SQL connection error displaying. Only a "500 Internal Server Error" that is returned in the network and console debug tab for the php file responsible for outputting the data.

My web server is set up with Nginx and PHP-FPM, and when checking the Nginx error log, in the VPS I use (Oracle with Ubuntu as the OS), I get a lot of SSL_do_handshake() failures, but I am unsure if that is related to this issue. I am using Cloudflare to receive a https certificate.

Here is the code for the relevent sections:

HTML:

```
  <section id="orderhistory">
   <div class="container text-center my-5">
    <h1>Order History</h1>
    <hr />
    <table class="rwd-table">
     <tbody id="users_purchases">
 
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
  </section>
```

JS

```
function get_all_purchases() {
      $.ajax({
          type : "GET",
          url : "CRUDprocess.php?get_purchases=1",
          dataType : 'html',
          success : function(response) {
              console.log(response);
              $("#users_purchases").html(response);
 
          }
      });
      }
```

I am then later declaring this function right after its definition as `get_all_purchases();`

PHP (CRUDprocess.php)

```
if (isset($_GET['get_purchases'])) {

$sql = "(sql query I'm checking for)";
 
$purchaseResults = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
 
if (mysqli_num_rows($purchaseResults) > 0) {
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($purchaseResults)) {
   (displays the table data)
```

Comment: What does your server's PHP error log say about the 500 response?

Comment: What command would I run to access the logs?

Comment: See [this Github issue](https://github.com/rlerdorf/php7dev/issues/48). You may need to enable error logging if it's not already on.

Comment: I access the file mentioned in this post and I only see a bunch of '~' with no other lines of code that I am lead to believe should be there.